# Export Excel and print document

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hello more beginner than me is not possible i think.
My new job involve that i have to learn quickly how ruby on rails works and understand all tips and methods previous programmers used on that project.
i use ruby v1.8.7 and rails 2.3.5
my target is to be able to print document and export to excel several arrays populated with databases data.
I already find out several messages here and tried them but i was not able to have one working fine.
i didn't succeed to have pdfkit working on my ubuntu server for sample.

Do someone know an easy method to :
export to excel (or csv) from a rails view
 - print to paper and print to pdf

Any tutorial would be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: This is really two separate questions, is it not?

Answer (score 0):

For the spreadsheet you might want to try [the spreadsheet gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/spreadsheet) which is an improvement over the old ParseExcel library.

Comment: Thanks i will make a try with this gem